# create a WEBSERVICE for CreditCard payment processing

Tags: c#-4.0

How to create a WEBSERVICE for CreditCard payment processing in C#.NET?

I want to process electronic payments. I am currently using PayPal but it costs too much. Many companies are able to provide electronic payments without using gateways. I imagine they use banks web service directly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to implement interface for each gateway: Authorize.net, SkipJack, Moneris, Mrw etc. Some of them give you a DLL to use their gateway or provide documentation how to make requests to API. Otherwise I think you need to implement interface for each bank you want to receive payment..

Comment: i have DLL for Payware,But, i want to web service for iphone application